# Can you do conditional asset storage with React Native

Tags: react-native, local-storage, storage, assets

I need to implement an application where assets (images) varies depending on the account type. The assets will be stuff like background images, so they are already predefined for each account type. I would like to use device storage for this, and I would like that an account only stores the assets associated with it, instead of having all assets stored for everyone. . For example:

Account A -> Device only stores assets for account A
Account B -> Device only stores assets for account B
Account C -> Device only stores assets for account C

Instead of having simultaneously stored assets for A, B, C accounts.The account type (predetermined) would be set at the beginning when users signup.

Is that possible with React Native?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't provide all the images in your bundle and use the client code to switch them based on account type?

Comment: @windowsill I am just afraid the bundle can get really big, and clients are going to be carrying assets that will never use. Do you think the bundle size is not a critical problem? I think they're only .jpg images. LMK what you think.

Comment: I have no idea! You haven't told me anything yet. A few dozen small images? No problem. Millions, that's a big problem.